# windows system (bootloader) partition accidently deleted during multiple installs

Tags: boot, windows

After experimenting with multiple variations of backtrack and xbmcbuntu variations of Ubuntu with dual boot successfully, my windows partition became unrecognizable to grub.

I used my windows boot CD to try to correct the problem. However, I deleted all partitions except for the NFTS one that contains my old windows install. (And, merged all other ones into that in hopes of getting back to the windows boot loader and out of grub)

Now, all I get is a grub command prompt when I try and boot the system (how??? - I thought I deleted grub) And, now the windows boot disc doesn't even recognize the install.

I've tried TRK to try and resolve the problem. Though I must admit ignorance in correctly using this utility.

I've searched for other answers to this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two paths to take:

## Getting into Windows

1. Boot a Ubuntu Live CD, and open Gparted. Right-click n your Windows partition(the one containing `boot.ini`, select the option to change flags, and ensure the boot flag is set.
2. Download and burn [Super Grub Disc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub.berlios/files/latest/download)(Not SGD2) and boot to it. Edit: gave correct link as first was SGD2 due to my stupidity
3. Select Windows in the SGD menu, and then in the submenu that appears, select "Fix Boot of Windows".
4. Reboot.

## Getting Ubuntu working along with Windows

1. Unfortunately, you need to have a separate Ubuntu partiton. If you can "unmerge" the partition in any way, then boot a live CD and open the Linux partition you have(It'll be on the left bar of the file manager, but *not* the root partiton, as that is the one used by the Live CD.
2. Open a terminal. Enter in the terminal:

   ```
   grub-install --root-directory=<Mount point of Linux partition> /dev/sda
   ```
3. You may get the mount point by opening Disk Utility(Palimpsest). Once you execute the command, Grub will be installed, hopefully recognizing the Windows partition. If you need to remove Grub and use the Windows loader, you will lose access to Ubuntu.(unless you chainload, which is outside the scope of this answer)

Consider having Grub on an external drive and booting to it to load Ubuntu, if nothing else works.

Edit: On SGD, I believe I may not have given perfect instructions. Try:Super Grub Disc->Choose Language and no Help->English->Windows->Fix Boot of Windows? If that fails, try the Activate partition option for your system(Desktop vs Laptop).

Answer (score 0):

You could always download and use [Resc-a-tux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

This is a live cd with a primary goal: Restoring grub/installing grub. It's a nice program which I used after windows just removed my grub without asking, and it worked like a charm. But in your case, you are installing Grub to boot windows, which isn't a problem at all. Just press restore grub, and it will make a bootloader for you.

> **Rescatux features:**
>
> Fixes GRUB and GRUB2
>
> Regenerates Debian/Ubuntu grub menues
>
> Check and fix filesystems
>
> Fixes Windows MBR
>
> Blank Windows passwords
>
> Boot Info Script
>
> Change Gnu/Linux password
>
> Regenerate sudoers file
>
> **Extra tools:**
>
> Synaptic
>
> Gparted 0.7

Comment: This one looks interesting. And, possibly within my skill level. =) I will try it next time I get myself in a bind with linux. (Which will prolly not be too far away....)

Comment: It's easy, that's what it was designed for ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather lazy method for this.

Short answer: make a new boot sector.

Longer answer: Reinstall windows on a seperate drive, it will detect and write a loader for the detected windows part.
After that, you can move the bootsector in windows.

Best way? probably not. Easy way? yes.
It might work, and pending you have the extra drive, it wont delete anything.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'm not sure I understand this method well enough to try it, though.